# Retrieving data bound object

Tags: c#, jquery, knockout.js

I created a ViewModel which has an observable property. I bind this array to an `ul` HTML element, like this:

```html
<ul id="sortable" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'parameterTemplate', 
                           foreach: parameters }, 
               visible: parameters().length > 0" 
    style="width: 100%">
</ul>
```

My template is this:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="parameterTemplate">
    <li class="ui-state-default parameterItem">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isRequired" />
        Name:
        <input data-bind="value: name " /> 
        Type:
        <input data-bind="value: type " /> 
        Size:
         <input data-bind="value: size " /> 
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</a>
    </li>
</script>
```

I'm using the draggable and sortable resources of jQuery to reorder the elements of the list. This means that when the users changes the order of the element, obviously ko databind is not altered, for jQuery does not know knockout exists.

It so happens that I want my `parameters` to be saved in the same order the user configured. So my approach was to select al the  `li` HTML elements via jQuery, getting an array (    `var items = $(".parameterItem");`) . How can I get , for each item in `items`, the databound knockout element, associated with the `li` HTML element?

Is it possible?

My View Model:

```
function parameter(parameterName, parameterType, parameterSize, descriptive, defaultValue, isRequired, ownerViewModel) {
    this.name = ko.observable(parameterName);
    this.type = ko.observable(parameterType);
    this.size = ko.observable(parameterSize);
    this.label = ko.observable(parameterName);
    this.descriptive = ko.observable(descriptive);
    this.defaultValue = ko.observable(defaultValue);
    this.descriptive = ko.observable(descriptive);
    this.isRequired = ko.observable(isRequired);
    this.ownerViewModel = ownerViewModel;
    this.remove = function () {
        ownerViewModel.parameters.remove(this)
    };
}

function excelLoaderViewModel() {
    this.parameters = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.newParameterName = ko.observable();
    this.newParameterType = ko.observable();
    this.newParameterSize = ko.observable();
    this.newParameterDescriptive = ko.observable();
    this.newParameterIsRequired = ko.observable();
    this.newParameterDefaultValue = ko.observable();

    this.systemName = ko.observable();

    this.addParameter = function () {
        this.parameters.push(
            new parameter(
                 this.newParameterName()
               , this.newParameterType()
               , this.newParameterSize()
               , this.newParameterDescriptive()
               , this.newParameterDefaultValue()
               , this.newParameterIsRequired()
               , this));
        this.newParameterName("");
        this.newParameterType("");
        this.newParameterSize("");
        this.newParameterIsRequired(false);
        this.newParameterDefaultValue("");
    }

var myVM = new excelLoaderViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a custom binding to keep your observableArray in sync with your elements as they are dragged/dropped.

Here is a [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html) that I wrote about it a while ago.

Here is a custom binding that works with jQuery Templates:

```
//connect items with observableArrays
ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var list = valueAccessor();
        $(element).sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                //retrieve our actual data item
                var item = ui.item.tmplItem().data;
                //figure out its new position
                var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);
                //remove the item and add it back in the right spot
                if (position >= 0) {
                    list.remove(item);
                    list.splice(position, 0, item);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Here is a sample of it in use: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vgXNX/

If you are using it with Knockout 1.3 beta without jQuery Templates (or with), then you can replace the `tmplItem` line with the new `ko.dataFor` method available in 1.3:

```
//connect items with observableArrays
ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var list = valueAccessor();
        $(element).sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                //retrieve our actual data item
                var item = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]);
                //figure out its new position
                var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);
                //remove the item and add it back in the right spot
                if (position >= 0) {
                    list.remove(item);
                    list.splice(position, 0, item);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: AWESOME! I pictured in my mind it would be possible, for in  MVVM pattern I'm able to get the bound item. This binding handlers are good. So, if I understood it correctly, you add a new "event" to `ko` and when it starts handling, it gets the `ul` element, which is a jQuery `sortable`. Whenever the `sortable` triggers the `update` event, you get the `ui.item`, which is a `li` and its bound item. Anyways I'm now reading knockout documentation concernign customBindings in order to have a full understanding of the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you are understanding.  At some point you would have written some code to traverse through the li elements, find their associated data, and try to reconstruct the array in the correct order.  The custom binding does a couple of things for you: 
1-it sets up the ul to be  sortable (no need to wire it up yourself)
2-it hooks up to the `update` event triggered by jQuery UI when an item is moved.  From there it identifies the new position of the li in the list and moves its associated data accordingly.